# The Meaning of EST

Tags: meaning

While I was reading Kristin Hanna's book *The Greater Alone* I encountered the term EST: 
"In the past few years, she’d tried **EST** and the human potential movement, spiritual training, Unitarianism. Even Buddhism. She’d cycled through them all, cherry-picked pieces and bits."

So I searched online for the meaning of this term but the results I found don't answer my question - they explain it's an abbreviation for established, estimated or Eastern Time Zone.

Is anyone acquainted with another meaning?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with an initialism essentially a proper noun, a business organisation. This is also easily googlable: "EST + Wikipedia".

Answer (score 2):

**Erhard Seminars Training**

> Erhard Seminars Training (marketed as est, though often encountered as EST or Est) was an organization founded by Werner Erhard in 1971 that offered a two-weekend (60-hour) course known officially as "The est Standard Training". This seminar aimed "to transform one's ability to experience living so that the situations one had been trying to change or had been putting up with, clear up just in the process of life itself".[2][3] An est site claims that it "brought to the forefront the ideas of transformation, personal responsibility, accountability, and possibility".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erhard_Seminars_Training

Disclaimer: I had never heard of this or the book, but it fits generally in the list of movements and religions one might explore if one were searching for greater meaning.

Comment: I googled EST and spirituality to find this. It fits with a list of things one might "try" within the new age and spirituality realm. Budhism is of course not New Age, but was explored as such by people in the US not from cultures that had the religion.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the prompt reply!

Comment: Yup, along with TM and half a dozen other fads from the 70s.

Comment: In The Americans, Philip goes to EST meetings. This is probably the most recent cultural reference.